# Resolving double-prefix addresses with apache2

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, ip-address

I have a server with public, static IP plus already configured DNS (GoDaddy) to link it to `dev.anExample.com` and wanted to setup additional hosts in following way:

`person1.dev.anExample.com`, `person2.dev.anExample.com`, etc.

I know how to proxy URLs to machines in my network (via apache2), but I've managed to setup only:

`person1.anExample.com`, `person2.anExample.com`, etc.

It's done by manually writing all entries to DNS table. How can I achieve it without entering data for each person manually?

The perfect scenario would be enter some record pointing to `dev.anExample.com` into DNS settings and let apache2 resolve incoming `(anything).dev.anExample.com` requests.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DNS, you can create a "wildcard" record for the `*` subdomain:

```
*.dev.anExample.com.  A  192.0.23.45
```

This way, when a client sends a DNS query for `something.dev.anExample.com` and there is no exact match, it will receive data from the wildcard entry instead.

Apache does not need to know about this – it receives identical HTTP requests in either case. Domain resolution is the job of DNS.